# Custom Javascript Thumbnail Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on creating a custom javascript thumbnail slider using data-src. Everything is working perfectly just the next button and prev button is not working at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the link to the codepen

https://codepen.io/mandipluitel/pen/BbOXgZ

I am using this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".thumbnails li").click(function(e){
    var thisDataSrc = $(this).attr("data-src");
    var thisDataCount = $(this).children().attr("data-count");
    if(thisDataSrc == "undefined"){}
    else{
      $(this).siblings("li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).parents(".thumbnails").next().find("img").attr("src",thisDataSrc);
      $(this).parents(".thumbnails").next().find("span.number").html("" + thisDataCount + "");
    }
  });

  $("button.next").click(function(e) {
    var currentDiv = 0;

    var newDataSrc = $(this).parents(".slider-hold").prev().find(".active").attr("data-src");
    if(newDataSrc == "undefined"){}
    else{
      currentDiv = currentDiv .next();
      currentDiv.siblings("li").removeClass("active");
      currentDiv.addClass("active");
      currentDiv.parents(".thumbnails").next().find("img").attr("src",newDataSrc);
    }
  });
});
```

Help here.

Comment: Are there errors in the console when you test it in a browser?

Comment: Please also include any error messages you are getting in your question, instead of just saying "It is not working".  This will help us help you get to an answer sooner!

Comment: @AndyG no there is no any console error. Can you please check the codepen url i updated the variable there the next button is working but its off sync and also its only working when i click twice for the first time.

Comment: @remy_rm so sorry for the confusion here. but actually there is no error message and Can you please check the codepen url i updated the variable there the next button is working but its off sync and also its only working when i click twice for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that currentDiv is set to zero. So when you later set it to currentDiv.next(), it doesn't really do anything.

I belive that the function should start something like this:

```
$("button.next").click(function(e) {
    var currentLi = $("li.active");
    var nextLi = currentLi.next();
    if (nextLi) {
        nextLi.siblings("li").removeClass("active");
        nextLi.addClass("active");
        $("#large-image").attr("src",nextLi.attr("data-src"));
    }
});
```

Comment: ah so sorry thanks, I forgot to specify the right variable, its added, but still I am having the same issue. The next button is only working when I click it twice for the first time and the coordination of active thumbnail and big image is totally wrong.

Comment: Ah, I thought I would only push you in the right direction :-) I've updated the answer. And I suggest adding "id" attributes to the html elements, so that you can use jquery selectors like "#large-image" instead of searching for them.